# Can you use the same seed for normal BTC and Lightning wallets?

Tags: lightning-network, seed, mnemonic-seed

If I generated 24 words from a Ledger Nano, can I import these to a lightning network wallet e.g. Eclair?

Answer (score 0):

A lightning network wallet *can* be compatible with a Ledger Nano generated wallet, but doesn't *have* to be.

Ledger nano generates seeds (the 24 words) using [BIP 32/BIP 39/BIP 44](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/2srxr2/what_is_the_difference_between_bip_32_and_bip_44/cnspxwq/).

I checked to see what format eclair uses, and it seems to use [BIP 49 instead of BIP 44](https://github.com/ACINQ/eclair/blob/master/eclair-core/src/main/scala/fr/acinq/eclair/blockchain/electrum/ElectrumWallet.scala#L386). This seems to suggest that the seeds are incompatible, but I haven't confirmed this.

If you want to do so, you can try importing your Ledger seeds into eclair, which is a non-descructive action (i.e. it won't affect your wallet/funds).

Comment: They should be compatible, BIP49 is the segwit extension of BIP44 (which is necessary for ln). The ledger seed should work fine

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the wallet. Currently, most lightning wallets use different methods for backing up and restoring your funds, as it's a little bit more complex than a regular bitcoin wallet.

But Phoenix for example does support BIP39 seeds so far.

It is also important to note that you should never use your seed from a hardware wallet in a software wallet. Moreover when it comes to lightning wallets you will still need channel backups to make sure you can restore your funds properly.